# Value of a and b via L-Hospital.

Tags: limits, power-series

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a\sin^2x \times b\log \cos x}{x^4} = \frac{1}{2}$.

As-

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a\sin^2x \times b\log \cos x}{x^4} = \frac{0}{0}\ \text{form}$$
Note that $$\sin^2x = x^2\bigg(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}+\cdots\bigg)^2,\qquad \cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$ As$$\log(1-y)= -\bigg(y+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+\cdots\bigg) $$ $$\implies \log \cos x = -\bigg[\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\bigg)+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\bigg)^2+\cdots\bigg] $$ Therefore  $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a\sin^2x \times b\log \cos x}{x^4}\hspace{90mm}$$ $$ = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^4 a\big(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}+\cdots\big)^2 \times (-b)\big[\big(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{4!}+\cdots\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}+\cdots\big)^2+\cdots\big] }{x^4}$$ $$ = (-ab)\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \implies ab = -1$$
But i need to find a and b? How to get that?

Comment: Using L'H rule or Taylor expansion for such a small case is more than necessary. Rather, the notion of equivalent infinitesimal suffices. Since $\sin x \sim x$ and $\log\cos x\sim (\cos x -1)=-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2} \sim -\frac{1}{2}x^2$, we can quickly conclude that $ab=-1$.

Comment: $ab=-1$ so any $(a,-a^{-1})$ with $a\neq 0$ is convenient.